# Why registration service in module is needed after registration in Injectable decorator?

Tags: angular

I am create the following service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: AppModule,
})
export class HttpStatusService {
  getValues() {
    return of(1, 2, 3);
  }
}
```

As you see this service is available in AppModule. However console displays the error message:

> ERROR Error: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[HttpStatusService ->
> HttpStatusService -> HttpStatusService]: NullInjectorError: No
> provider for HttpStatusService!

I need the following string of code in AppModule:

```
providers: [HttpStatusService]
```

But this string of code works fine without:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: AppModule,
})
```

I think that `providedIn: AppModule,` is reduntant. Isnt it?

[link to demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jtsaqt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fhttp-status.service.ts)

Comment: `providedIn:` Module is deprecated. You shouldn't use it.  You likely want `providedIn: 'root'`

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler official doc  speak that providedIn: Module isnt deprecated: https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules

Comment: It is here : https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable